# integer points on conics

Tags: conic-sections

The following lines are from Schinzels paper "integer points on conics"

Let $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey +f = 0$ be a non-degenerate conic over integers.

Setting $X= \delta x+be-2cd$, $Y=\delta y+bd-2ae$, where $\delta=b^2-4ac$, we get
$$aX^2 +bXY+cY^2=4\delta \Delta \ \ \ (2) $$ 
for some integer $\Delta$.

Let $(u_0,v_0)$ be the least positive solution for 
$u^2-4\delta^3v^2=4$ and set 
$\varepsilon=(\frac{u_0+2\delta \sqrt{\delta}v_0}{2})^2  $.

If $X_0,Y_0$ is a solution of (2) and satisfies the congruences 
$$ X_0 \equiv be-2cd \bmod \delta,\ \ \ Y_0 \equiv bd-2ae \bmod \delta$$
then also every solution $X,Y$ of 
$$ 2aX +(b+\sqrt{\delta})Y =    (2aX_0 +(b+\sqrt{\delta})Y_0) \varepsilon ^n$$satisfies these congrunces. Therefore we can assume that 
$$ 4 \sqrt{|a\delta\Delta|} \leq |2aX_0 +(b+\sqrt{\delta})Y_0| \leq  4 \sqrt{|a\delta\Delta|}\varepsilon $$
Question: Can somebody explain me why we can assume this?

Comment: do you have a link to the article? I do not see it online, although I can get a scan from the campus library in a few days

Comment: hmmm. No, they do not have that volume, or the later volume with the errata

Comment: Dear Will,
thank you very very much for your time! 
I didn't recieve any notification for your answer, so I am replying quite late... This is actually the erata.
I missed to write that epsilon>1, so if  you concider
|2aX_0+(b+δ√)Y_0|>4|aδΔ| 
then multiplying (2aX0+(b+δ√)Y0) by the conjugate of epsilon which is <1 you get a smaller solution which is a contrudiction to the assumption...

Comment: Of course if you want to see the paper i can scan it and send it you...
Thanks again!